# Sharepoint server 2013 slow performance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Recently upgraded from 2010 to 2013
everything works fine but the performance is very slow
whenever i open sherepoint designer it take too much time to communicate with the server 
especially after enabling Enterprise services in central adminstration

Comment: Is only SPD slow? Or is the response time in browser slow as well? What is your farm configuration?

Comment: I found out that im having problem with my server Memory